# Singly Linked List swap function (int, int)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, int, swap, singly-linked-list

I think my problem lies in the usage of push_backs() but I can't think of a simple way around this problem. I need it to swap the nodes at the two ints given in the arguements, I appreciate any help! I'm a college freshman making my way in the world today, and am open to feedback!

```
void MyList::swap(int i, int j)
{
   if (i == j || i > size() || j > size()) return;

   Node *temp = head;
   delete head; //pretty sure this is what's giving me issues as well

   for (unsigned x = 0; x < size(); x++)
   {

      if (x == i)
      {
         int y = 0;
         for (Node *itt = head; itt; itt = itt->next)
         {
            if (y == j)
               push_back(itt->value);
            y++;
         }
      }
      else if (x == j)
      {
         int y = 0;
         for (Node *itt = head; itt; itt = itt->next)
         {
            if (y == i)
               push_back(itt->value);
            y++;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         push_back(temp->value);
      }

      temp = temp->next;
   }
}
```

for reference, here is the Node class

```
  using namespace std;
  class Node
  {
   public:
        char value;
        Node *next;
        Node(char value)
        :value(value), next(0)
    {}
   };
```

Comment: Yes, the `delete head` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you later dereference `head`. Why do want to free the memory of the head node? Especially when you're going to use it later?

Comment: Because the MyList is defined by "head" and I can't add things to a full list, as I see it. haha

Comment: You should read this article on [debugging your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just swap the values of the ith and jth nodes.

```
void MyList::swap(int i, int j){
  if(head == NULL) return;

  // Get ith node
  node* node_i = head;
  int node_cnt = 0;
  while(1){
    if(node_cnt == i) break;  
    if(node_i == NULL) return; 
    node_i = node_i->next;
    node_cnt++;
  } 

  // Get jth node
  node* node_j = head;
  node_cnt = 0;
  while(1){
    if(node_cnt == j) break;  
    if(node_j == NULL) return; 
    node_j = node_j->next;
    node_cnt++;
  }

  // Swap values of nodes
  int temp = node_i->value;
  node_i->value = node_j->value;
  node_j->value = temp;
}
```

Comment: Swapping the values only works for this example. It will need to be changed if the implementation of `Node` changes (violates the Open/Closed principle).

Comment: Very nice, aside from the very small mistake at the end, it works wonderfully, and I never thought to do that! thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better approach than yours. You really don't need to `delete` anything. You only need to get a pointer to the node preceding the ith node (if any) and a pointer to the node preceding the jth node (if any). Then do the swap.